# Find the immediate square dancing neighbors, they dance together to perfect square

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers, number-theory

We live in a community of houses sequentially numbered from 1 to 100. We all love square dancing but only two immediate neighbors are joy to watch. If you concatenate their house numbers, it forms a true square.

Who are they?

Comment: Very nice puzzle! I'll admit that I found this by checking a lot of possibilities (by hand, not programming anything), but there's a very neat mathematical solution which yields the solution almost without any calculation at all.

Comment: Thx..during my long walks I come up with these..I love to do mental math..I can square most of the numbers upto 1000 mentally..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> $8281$, the concatenation of 82 and 81, which is $91^2$.

Proof:

> We're looking for a perfect square of the form $xyxz$ where $z=y\pm1$. But this equals $101(10x+y)\pm1$, which is congruent to $\pm1$ modulo $101$. So its square root must be less than $100$ but congruent to a square root of $\pm1$ modulo 101.

One of the two cases can be eliminated immediately:

> The square roots of $+1$ modulo $101$ are $\pm1$, which are not possibilities. (Note that $101$ is prime, so there are exactly two square roots.)

So we check the other one.

> What are the square roots of $-1$ modulo $101$? Clearly $10^2\equiv-1$, but that doesn't give us the solution we need. The other square root is $-10\equiv91$, and that does give us the solution.

QED.

Comment: Very neat mathematical proof for general case